# VSCODE: How to make MDN Reference link double click?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you hover over things there is a pop-up with MDN Reference and I always accidently click it hence I want to make it double click instead of single click because I don't want to remove it completely.
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible so I requested the feature in their github

Answer (score 0):

Just go to VSCode -> Preferences -> Settings, search "editor hover disable" and enable the checkbox.

Comment: the hover shows important information in javascript without the annoying link, so I need to keep it